# Let T : $P_4(F)$ → $P_4(F)$ be the differentiation operator Tp = p'

Tags: linear-algebra

a) Is $T$ surjective?

b) If $(1, z, z^2, z^3, z^4)$ is the standard basis for $P_4(F)$, write down $T(1), T(z), T(z^2), T(z^3), T(z^4).$

c) With respect to this basis for both domain and codomain, and your calculations above, write down $M(T)$.

Ok, so I started working and so far I have this:

a) $T$ is not surjective because the polynomial $x^4$ is not in the range of T.

b) $T(1) = 0, T(z) = 1, T(z^2) = 2z, T(z^3) = 3z^2, T(z^4) = 4z^3.$ **//Not sure here**

c) Is this a 5x5 matrix with 0's everywhere except the diagonal with (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)?

Comment: why are you unsure about $b$??

Comment: a) is correct. b) is correct, I don't know why they mention the basis at the start.

Comment: @copper.hat perhaps they expect $T(z^k)$ to be written as coordinate vectors rather than polynomials.

Comment: @copper.hat (b) I guess I thought maybe it should be (0,1,z,z^2,z^3), but maybe I was thinking too much into it.

Comment: what about part c y'all?

Comment: No, the nonzero entries are not on the diagonal, but rather on the first superdiagonal.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that for b), they expect each of the polynomials $T(z^k)$ to be written as coordinate vectors over the basis $B = (1,z,z^2,z^3,z^4)$.  For example, we have
$$
[T(1)]_B = [0]_B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
[T(z^4)]_B = [4z^3]_B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0\\4\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Can you do this for the other vectors?  Note that for any linear operator $T$, the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $B = (v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is simply the matrix whose columns are $[T(v_1)]_B ,\dots,[T(v_n)]_B$.  So, according to the above, you should have
$$
[T]_B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&?&?&?&0\\
0&?&?&?&0\\
0&?&?&?&0\\
0&?&?&?&4\\
0&?&?&?&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I'll leave it to you to fill in the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b_k = z \mapsto z^k$, $k=0,...,4$. Then $T b_k = k b_{k-1}$ for $k=1,...4$ and $T b_0 = 0$.

Let $e_k$ be the vector of zeros with a one in the $k$th position ($e_0 = (1,0,0,0,0)^T$). Let $A=M(T)$. Then we have $Ae_k = k e_{k-1}$ $k=1,...4$ and $A e_0 = 0$.